# Sails Create multiple instance of a module in Sails

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I'm trying to create 2 user in parallel and wait for it to be created after do something else. I was trying to use:

```
Promise.all([User.create(usr1), User.create(usr2), User.create(usr3)]).then(function(){
console.log("\o/");
}
```

without luck, because `User.create()` do not return a Promise.

I also tried:

```
User.create([usr1, usr2]).then(function(){
  console.log('x') 
})
```

**Error** that I get:

```
[Error (E_VALIDATION) 1 attribute is invalid] Invalid attributes sent to undefined:
• user
• A record with that user already exists (null).
```

Ugly code that is working:

```
 User.create([usr1]).then(function(){ 
    User.create[usr2].then(function(){ console.log('x') });
 });
```

Also work with .exec()

```
User.create([usr1, usr2]).exec(function(){
  console.log('x') 
})
```

How can I use Promise or just waterline to create two user?

**EDIT:**
1) Calling it in mocha test

[Code here](https://github.com/makah/sails-rateSite/)

```
attributes: {
    name: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },        
    email: {
        type: 'email',
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: 'string',
        minLength: 6,
    },

    //Association One-to-One, but using 'collection' to mantain sync updating
    employer: {
        collection: 'employer',
        via: 'user'
    },

    employee: {
        collection: 'employee',
        via: 'user'
    },

    //Google Signin ID
    googleId: 'string',

    //Access token from the Google Authorization Server
    googleAccessToken: 'string',

    resetPasswordToken: String,
    resetPasswordExpires: Date,

    toJSON: function() {
        var obj = this.toObject();
        delete obj.password;
        delete obj.resetPasswordToken;
        delete obj.resetPasswordExpires;

        return obj;
    }
},
```

**EDIT<sup>2</sup>:**

This error only happens when I use sails-disk, in sails-mongo work

Comment: For me, both the first and the second method work just fine. What does your `User`model look like?

Comment: hi @Fissio I have edited the question with my model